# Wordpress installation infected

Tags: wordpress

my problem is, that my wordpress installation was infected. So I downloaded the whole files and checked them by V-scan. It seems to be okay, but google-pages find an deeper problem.

here you can see the page: best-around.de

Now I want change all files via ftp. (no new installation) ... I extracted the new version of wordpress.

And now my question is, which data i need from the old installation (like wp-config.php). So that I can changes only the files.

Thanks and kind regards
Armin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to keep.

`wp-config.php` stores your database connection details and a few other settings.

`wp-content` is the directory that stores all of your uploads and plugins. Essentially all of your uploaded content.

The file and folder shown above are what you would typically want to keep. However, the infection could very well have spread to the php files in there too - so keep that mind!

The alternative method is listed below:

A good idea would be to follow the manual upgrade process instead

1. Get the latest WordPress zip (or tar.gz) file.
2. Unpack the zip file that you downloaded.
3. Deactivate plugins.
4. Delete the old wp-includes and wp-admin directories on your web host (through your FTP or shell access).
5. Using FTP or your shell access, upload the new wp-includes and wp-admin directories to your web host, in place of the previously deleted directories.
6. Upload the individual files from the new wp-content folder to your existing wp-content folder, overwriting existing files. Do NOT delete your existing wp-content folder. Do NOT delete any files or folders in your existing wp-content directory (except for the one being overwritten by new files).
7. Upload all new loose files from the root directory of the new version to your existing wordpress root directory.

If you get stuck here - have a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick response. I understand up to point 5. In Point 6 you say "upload the individual files" from the new wp-content. What are the individual files? And what are "loose files"? thanks

Comment: Anytime :) With regards to point 6: you need to copy over all of the files inside wp-content from the newly downloaded wordpress directory, to your old installation directory.

Comment: With regards to point7: copy all of the "spare files" as in the actual .php files (except wp-config) from your newly downloaded wordpress directory, into your public_html folder (it may be named something entirely different depending on your host, but it is the folder that has the wp-config.php file in it.)

Comment: Okay thanks. I have to try now, but i seems that it works :) I woll tell you later. Kind regards Armin

Comment: so i´m done ... for the first time it seems good, but there must be something other (maybe plugin) where the hacks come in. Thank you for your quick guide to make an clean installation on an easy way.